# What is the best way to categorize/code political affiliation? Can I make it an ordinal variable?

Tags: logistic, spss, ordinal-data, categorical-encoding

I have coded 'Political Leftness' as the variable and coded:

0=Right

1=Center

2=Left

But I am not sure that this works or if there is a glaring error in coding it as ordinal data. Is there a better way to code political affiliation as scale data? I want to run a Binary Logistic Regression if possible so I am trying to avoid nominal categories.

Comment: It depends how you approach the measurement of this variable and how it was measured and operationalized before in the literature. I think it is more common to use left-right ideological self-placement question with a 10- or 11-point response scale (see European Social Survey, World Values Survey, or General Social Survey). The last part of your question is not clear. What do you mean by "I want to run a Binary Logistic Regression if possible so I am trying to avoid nominal categories"? Why do you prefer binary logistic regression?